# Closed set in bidual

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a locally convex Hausdorff topological real vector space $E$ and a compact subset $Z\subseteq E$. Now let $E^*$ be the topological dual of $E$ and consider the canonical embedding $\iota: E\rightarrow (E^*)^{'}$ into the algebraic dual of $E^*$ where $(E^*)^{'}$ is equipped with the $\sigma((E^*)^{'},(E^*))$-topology. I want to know why $\iota(Z)$ is closed in $(E^*)^{'}$.

Any help/hints will be grateful appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\iota$ is continuous, and $Z$ is compact, so $\iota(Z)$ is compact.  Since $(E^*)'$ is Hausdorff, it follows that $\iota(Z)$ is closed.